# Drupal 7 which hook is called when user updates any field in configuration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, I am looking for a hook that is called when user update the value of any field in configuration area so that I could update it on other locations using custom module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you wish to write a custom module that makes changes to other data in the CMS upon submission of a form, using data from that particular form.

To do this you could use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` (see the [official Drupal API docs for details](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x)) in your `.module` file to specify a new submission callback function like so:

```
function YOURCUSTOMMODULENAME_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
     $form['#submit'][] = 'my_callback_function';
}

function my_callback_function($form, &$form_state)
{
     //Whatever code you want to execute here to update other fields
}
```

The code above targets a specific form by id, but  you can use the more generic `hook_form_alter` to target all forms. See the API docs for more details on which order these form hooks fire in and what parameters they each need.

Answer (score 0):

When you update a field user you have to do it by this way

```
$user->name= 'new-username';
user_save($user);
```

When you call `user_save` function you are calling the next hook:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7.x

```
hook_user_update
```

Comment: I dont want to update user field, question is if someone update and value in admin panel , i want to call a hook